# Filtering a list of tuples

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have a list of tuples and I want to filter out the all elements where the second value in the tuple is not equal to 7.

I do:

```
valuesAsList.filter(x=>x._2 != 7)
```

Can I use wildcard notation to make this even shorter?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try?  Wherever you see `x => ... x ...` replace with `... _ ...`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can

```
valuesAsList.filter(_._2 != 7)
```

But I doubt it should be preferred over your example or this (think readability):

```
valuesAsList.filter {case (_, v) => v != 7}
```

Comment: FWIW, I would always write `filter(_._2 != 7)`, not any of the larger clumsier stuff.  I don't care about `v`, just `_2 != 7`; everything else distracts.  `_.` is the minimal distraction possible.

Comment: Second is more readable because you can give `v` a name, which would describe what you are comparing against `7` with.

Answer (score 3):

Fairly straight forward, with no real advantage IMHO:

```
valuesAsList.filter(_._2 != 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

For array of tuples, we can use for with yield which will returns an array

scala> val str = Array((2,Hello), (3,MyNameIs), (8,Lolo))

res34: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((2,Hello), (3,MyNameIs), (8,Lolo))

scala> for(i <- str if(i._2.size > 4)) yield (i._1,i._2.toLowerCase)

res35: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((2,hello), (3,mynameis))

Comment: This 6 year old question requests a shorter solution. You've provided a much longer one.